# Why I can not append the values from dictionary to array in iOS?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, null

I am trying to get the keys and values from dictionary and trying to add into an array.But I am getting an null pointer exception.

```
 var denominationValues:[String]! -----> Array Declaraion
 for (denomination,productId) in tariffPackageDetailsArray[indexPath.row].tariffPlanDenominationAndProductId!
 {
    denominationValues.append(productId)
  }
```

if I print those values I am getting the correct values.But why I can not add it to the array? What mistake I am doing?Anyone please help me....Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The array is declared but not initialized

```
var denominationValues = [String]()
```

Answer (score 4):

you are not allocating the memory for your array just declared

```
 var denominationValues = [String]()
```

or you could use

```
 var denominationValues: [String] = []
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use a high order transformation function from the standard library called `map(_:)`. This function loops through a collection and gives an access to each element and apply your transformation to it, then returns a new collection with elements which are a result of the transformation.

```
var denominationValues = tariffPackageDetailsArray[indexPath.row].tariffPlanDenominationAndProductId?.map { $0.value }
```

Comment: Please, read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) topic. Since your answer covers the question, it is worth to explain the details.

Answer (score 0):

The array should be declared as well as initialized if you need to append some values.

```
var array = [Int]() // Declaring and initializing in one line

var array: [Int]? // Declaring array
array = [Int]() //initializing array
```

Only declaring the array and not initializing works only when you assign an array value itself to the array you declared.

```
var array: [Int]?
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array = array1
```